# Como puedo trabajar con GraphQl en laravel 8?

Tags: api, graphql, laravel-8

Estoy intentando crear un proyecto con laravel 8 que incluya una API GraphQl, y me encontré con un error al intentar instalar `lighthouse-php`, se instala pero no creó la carpeta GraphQl en Routes `("Routes/GraphQl")`, la crea en la raiz del proyecto

También unos problemas al intentar registrar el proveedor del servicio `("$app->register(\Nuwave\Lighthouse\LighthouseServiceProvider::class);")` en `bootstrap/app.php`. También intenté `rebing/graphql-laravel` `(https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel)`. Ayuda, estos son los errores:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in C:\laragon\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:830 Stack trace: #0 
C:\laragon\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(830): ReflectionClass->__construct('config') #1 

C:\laragon\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(712): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config') #2 

C:\laragon\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(796): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array, true) #3 

C:\laragon\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(651): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('config', Array) #4 

C:\laragon\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(781): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array) #5 

C:\laragon\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider.php(127): Il in 

C:\laragon\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 832
```

Estos errores me aparecen al incluir el proveedor del servicio `("$app->register(\Nuwave\Lighthouse\LighthouseServiceProvider::class);")` en `bootstrap/app.php`

Comment: Ayudaría que agregues esos errores a tu pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, ya agregue los errores, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Intenta de eliminar

```
$app->register(\Nuwave\Lighthouse\LighthouseServiceProvider::class);
```

en app/bootstrap y pon

```
\Nuwave\Lighthouse\LighthouseServiceProvider::class
```

bajo de 'providers' en config/app.php.